# Building AliBaba java example

Tags: java, rdf, sesame

Good evening,

I am new to Java Persistence API and I would like to test AliBaba to see what it could do.
[AliBaba website](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-beta14/index.html). I read part of [the exemple given here](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-rc1/alibaba-repository-object/index.html#Object%20Repository). I have the whole AliBaba project and two files for the exemple, I modified a little the exemple.

```
//Document.java
package org.openrdf.example;

import org.openrdf.annotations.Iri;

@Iri(Document.NS + "Document")
public class Document {
public static final String NS = "http://meta.leighnet.ca/rdf/2009/gs#";

@Iri(NS + "title") String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

And my other file:

```
//my Main with many imports
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException {
    // create a Document
    Document doc = new Document();
    // give it a title
    doc.setTitle("Getting Started");
    System.out.println("Title of the new document: "+doc.getTitle());
    
    // add a Document to the repository
    ObjectConnection con = repository.getConnection();
    // the problem is here
```

My problem is located in the line:

```
ObjectConnection con = repository.getConnection();
```

I have nowhere a declaration of 'repository'.
But I get an error for the object type.

Thank you for you help, i hope my writting is understandable as it is my first post here.

Comment: the user documentation is in their website: [link](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#section-repository-api)

Comment: thank you for this link, i don't know how i didn't see it. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an in-memory Sesame repository like this:

```
// create a repository
Repository store = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());
store.initialize();

// wrap in an object repository
ObjectRepositoryFactory factory = new ObjectRepositoryFactory();
ObjectRepository repository = factory.createRepository(store);
```

Comment: Thank you for your indications, I needed to create a repository. In fact, in the documentation that I first read, the developpers assume that you understood the whole concept of repositories. With the previously linked documentation and your exemple, it's more understandable.